# Different shaped object's curvature graphs.

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to calculate curvature graphs of different 2d objects programmatically. I am a clueless math student who doesn't know where to start. I want guide for this problem.

Before I deep dive into this I need to know if this curvature graphs are unique for every shape.

If they are unique can I apply same algorithm or formula to every shape for example circles, squares, some L shapes etc.?

And finally to achieve this where should I start and what should I learn over all?

thanks in advance. if I couldn't make myself clear sorry for that English is not my native language. I will try my best to make myself clear if there will be any problem.

Comment: If you mean curvature in the usual sense, the curvature of a square or L shape is zero except at the corners, where you pick up a multiple (the angle) times a $\delta$ function. A circle has constant curvature equal to $1/r$, where $r$ is its radius.

Comment: i am trying to identify different shapes from curvature graphs. i am gonna start top-left of the corner and calculate every points curvature and its gonna give me zero for edge length then in the corner give me angle of it. and its not only about these shapes. i am gonna use this to image process for a relatively small group of objects.